# Live edit in PhpStorm

Tags: google-chrome, phpstorm

I want live edit chrome page just like in inspector. I try to make some changes in code, but page still looks not changed.
I tried execute js code and its work, but what can I do with html..?

Comment: Have you set your project to auto-upload changed files?

Answer (score 0):

You need starting JavaScript Debug session to enable Live Edit. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Edit+in+PhpStorm